# UITouches not detecting

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode

My UItouches is not detecting in my Slideshow nib file. What is the problem? Can anyone help?

---

```
@class Slideshow;
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController{
PreferencesController *preferencesController;
Slideshow *slideshow;}
```

Slideshow Implementation

```
@implementation Slideshow
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
NSLog(@"touches begin");
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

UIImageView *frontView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
frontView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
frontView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"];
frontView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[self.view addSubview:frontView];

[frontView release];
}@end
```

Comment: What type of class is Slideshow? Does it inherit from UIResponder?

Answer (score 0):

Slideshow is a `UIViewController` and `touchesBegan` is only called on a `UIView`.  You need to subclass `UIView` to capture touches.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to xcode. So what code should I add to my current code to subclass UIView?